# How to get the type of a field using reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection, types

Is there a way to get the Type of a field with scala reflection?

Let's see the standard reflection example:

```
scala> class C { val x = 2; var y = 3 }
defined class C
scala> val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
m: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror ...
scala> val im = m.reflect(new C)
im: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for C@5f0c8ac1
scala> val fieldX = ru.typeOf[C].declaration(ru.newTermName("x")).asTerm.accessed.asTerm
fieldX: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TermSymbol = value x
scala> val fmX = im.reflectField(fieldX)
fmX: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.FieldMirror = field mirror for C.x (bound to C@5f0c8ac1)
scala> fmX.get
res0: Any = 2
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
val test: Int = fmX.get
```

That means can I "cast" the result of a reflection `get` to the actual type of the field? And otherwise: is it possible to do a reflection `set` from a string? In the example something like

```
fmx.set("10")
```

Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the deal... the type is not known at compile time, so, basically, you have to tell the compiler what the type it's supposed to be. You can do it safely or not, like this:

```
val test: Int = fmX.get.asInstanceOf[Int]

val test: Int = fmX.get match {
  case n: Int => n
  case _      => 0 // or however you want to handle the exception
}
```

Note that, since you declared `test` to be `Int`, you *have* to assign an `Int` to it. And even if you kept `test` as `Any`, at some point you have to pick a type for it, and it is always going to be something static -- as in, in the source code.

The second case just uses pattern matching to ensure you have the right type.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the second case.